# How do I redirect the page if the fetch api returns status code 302

Tags: javascript, http-headers, fetch

I have a button with functionality that requires the user to authenticate. If the user is not authenticated the link should redirect to the login page. When I click the button, from the devtools network tab I can see the fetch api first calls the original url which returns a status code 302 and then another call which returns the login page. So Instead of calling the login page after a 302 status code, I want to redirect the page there.

I have tried to use the `location` header but the result is always null and also for some reason the `if(res.status == 302)` block never executes

Here is the code

```
fetch(`https://example.com`)
    .then(res => {
        if(res.status == 302) {
            window.location.href = res.headers.get('location');
        } 
        else if (res.ok) return res.text();
        else console.log(`Error: ${res.status}`);
    })
    .then(data => {
        // Do something
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.error(e);
    });
});
```

Comment: what do you get in the console if you put `console.log(res.status)` just before that `if` statement (or if you step through with the debugger)?

Comment: @RobinZigmond 200

Comment: actually scratch that, from consulting MDN it seems that you should be able to look at `res.redirected` instead to detect a redirect

Comment: @RobinZigmond On the network tab it shows 2 entries, one 302 and one 200

Comment: sorry, I was misunderstanding how `fetch` behaved in this case (never seen it in action with redirects). See my previous comment, check `res.redirected`

Comment: I think `fetch()` follows redirects automatically and transparently, you don't need to check for 302 explicitly.